# Where are StatefulJob executed?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, debugging, quartz-scheduler

**Scenario**
I have been assigned to a new app. This app executes 20 `StatefulJob`s that runs in the background processing folders. It works nice, but now I have to create a new single Job and need to stop the others in order to debug with less noise.

**Problem**
When I debug, I find 20 threads like:

```
Thread [defaultQuartzConfiguration_Worker-5] (Running)
```

But I can't find where are executed.

**What I've tried**

- Searched for `Runnable`, `TaskExecutor`, `QuartzJobBean`, `TaskScheduler`, `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` but all I find in my project folders is inside `jar` files from `Spring` and `Quartz`.
- Tried to make a reverse search by call hierarchy to find origin
- Search for `xml` files that launch `Quartz` tasks

But no success. :(

After reading lot of doc, and searching inside I've found a class that launch some `Triggers` that seemed to be the multiple threads

```
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
    .newTrigger()
    .withIdentity("taskTrigger_" + c.getSubgrupo(), "TRIGGERS")
    .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(
          this.configBC.getConfig("FOLDER_PROCESS",
          c.getSubgrupo(), "CRON", true).get(0).getValor())).build();
```

But if I remove this triggers or debug `@PostConstruct` of the class, 10 of the `Worker`s are still there...

**Question**
 There is some trick to find the origin of this Trheads?

Comment: If your project uses spring it may have been configured either in xml or with annotations. So first thing I'd do is check if there are classes inside the project implementing `StatefulJob` and see where they're triggered. If this this does not work, it would be helpful to understand the setup of your project to know what to look for.

Comment: Thanks @Morfic, I've found some triggers, I updated question... Trying to understand how project works is what I'm trying, but I have zero experience with `Quartz` and creator of the project is not available... :(

Comment: Those [trigger definitions](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/TriggerBuilder.html) are used in combination with job definitions to schedule various runs. Next I'd look where they are getting invoked and track down the job building as well as where they get submitted to the scheduler. You can find more info regarding the job/trigger builders in the [tutorials](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/tutorials/)